# Laravel selectRange Adding Options To

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how I can use Laravel's selectRange to do an array of A-Z of options however add a default option that will reside as the first value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything? (no)

Comment: This is not possible with Laravels `selectRange`. Do it yourself. Build an array with all the options and use the normal `Form::select`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to lukasgeiter for his comment. I was able to create an array and pass that array to the normal select field.